# Usage of spring integration lockregistry outside of spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

We are looking for a rudementory distributed lock manager. I found the jdbclock registry inside spring integration quite compelling. What I couldn't figure our from spring integrations reference guide is if I  can use it for our own use case ( unrelated to message aggregation ). Can someone help me out here ?  Would it interfere with spring integration  if I do register a lockregistry bean and use it for my arbitray use case ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fully possible to use this and many other distributed computation features without any messaging in your application. To be frankly this is mostly the Hazelcast Spring Integration extension is popular for.

We had an idea before to extract all these cluster related features into the separate project, but we didn’t have a chance to do that.

Comment: It's a good idea to extract these features into separate project. Recently I tried to find out if there are any project already exist under Spring umbrella to allow easily create distributed locks with interchangeable backend plugins (like Hazelcast, Zookeper, JDBC, Redis, Mongo etc), and I was very surprised that this functionality comes from `spring-integration`. :-) Another project I found is https://github.com/alturkovic/distributed-lock just FYI. It's almost identical in ideas but uses annotations +BPP to setup locks.